# What is the meaning of "the sun a coin"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ellipsis, metaphors, gapping

> Cavendish is hollow-faced and hollow-eyed when he throws him on to a
> fresh horse at first light. ‘Call in some favours. There's hardly a
> gentleman in the realm that doesn't owe my lord cardinal something.’
>
> It's late October, **the sun a coin** barely flipped above the horizon.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Should I understand "*the sun a coin*" as "*the sun looks like a coin*"?

Comment: Yea, that's what I take it to mean, that the sun is very low, looks similar to a coin (probably gold coin). And referencing that it's probably just the start of sunrise since the coin (sun) was just flipped so it's going upwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to fill in the missing pieces to get the full sense:

> It is late October, [**and**] the sun [**is (like)**] a coin [**which is**] barely flipped above the horizon.

This is a metaphor, since it is fully equating two different things that are not the same. If it had used *like* or *as*, it would be a simile.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "the sun a coin barely flipped above the horizon" is a nominative absolute. This kind of construction includes two phrases; the first (which I've put in bold below) is a nominative phrase while the second (which I've put in italics below) is usually a modifier. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute) gives several examples, including:

> **The dragon** *slain*, the knight took his rest.
>
> We sit side by side, **our legs** *touching*, comfortable in the warm silence our two bodies create.

However, sometimes the second phrase is not a modifier but instead an appositive. That is the case with your sentence:

> It's late October, **the sun** *a coin barely flipped above the horizon*.

It is possible to infer that some words have been omitted to yield a different kind of sentence (with no nominative absolute), but I think that in this case doing so would require the reader to infer too many words. Considering the phrase after the comma to be a nominative absolute is the most straightforward way to understand this sentence.